Change of coordinates in a potential energy
I am having some confusions in what should be basic pointwise Newtonian mechanics, and would like to get some help with that. It is all about changing coordinates in potential energies.
Let us start by considering a point particule in a 2d world with an axis $x$ (left-right) and an axis $z$ (up-down) with constant gravitational acceleration $g$ (like on Earth). Said particle, of mass $m$, lies on a ground of shape $z = f(x)$.

In what follows, I will further refine the analysis to $z = \alpha x^2$.
What I think to be true (tell me if it's not !)
While the potential energy of the particle is $V(x) = mg \alpha x^2$, which is quadratic - like $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ - its motion is not that of an harmonic oscillator. The reason behind that is that the kinetic energy reads
\begin{equation}
T = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{z}^2) = \frac{1}{2}m(1+4\alpha^2x^2)\dot{x}^2
\end{equation}
So that conservation of energy yields
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}m(1+4\alpha^2x^2)\dot{x}^2 + mg \alpha x^2 = cst
\end{equation}
Which is not of the form required for an harmonic oscillator, namely $\dots \dot{x}^2 + \dots x^2 = cst$.
To get an harmonic oscillator, the choice of $f(x)$ should be different : essentially, one should introduce $s$ the curvilinear abscissa along the $z=f(x)$ curve, so that $T = m \dot{s}^2/2$, and choose $f$ so that $f(s) \propto s^2$.
My problem
Why can I just not write (as the usual ``think of potential energies as landscapes on which a ball can roll'' way of thinking goes):
\begin{equation}
V(x) = \alpha m g x^2
\end{equation}
And use from there Newton's law of motion to derive, with $\vec{r}$ the position of the mass $m$:
\begin{equation}
m \ddot{\vec{r}} = - \vec{\nabla} V = - 2 \alpha m g x \vec{e}_x
\end{equation}
which projected on the $x$-axis, yields
\begin{equation}
m \ddot{x} = - 2 \alpha m g x
\end{equation}
which is an harmonic oscillator equation ?
In general,

Why can't I change coordinates in potential energies?
How to know which choices of coordinates lead to correct results?


I think you need to be much more careful about what is actually $z$ and what are $x$. That is the most obvious place for confusion mistakes to arise.

Sure, but how do I actually do that ? Could you please provide an answer to the question where this distinction is carefully done ? Thanks !

Note: the question was closed, but no reason was given. If anyone feels like to explain me why, I'd be glad to understand it...

You have a 2D system, and in 2D the potential of a SHO is $V(\mathbf r) = \tfrac12k|r|^2$, where in this case $|r|^2 = x^2 + z^2$. Your system is not a SHO because in your system the potential is just $mgz$. It has nothing to do with coordinates, your system is just not an SHO.


Why can I just not write [...] $V(x)=\alpha mgx^2$ and use from there Newton's law of motion to derive [...] the position of the mass $m\ddot{r⃗}=−∇⃗ V$

One simple answer is that the force from the gravitational potential is not the only one that is acting on the mass. The constraint $z=\alpha x^2$ is just a way of stating "there are other (unknown) forces that constrain the mass on this curve". In fact, without this constraint the mass would just fall down vertically. But it doesn't, because other forces are acting. These forces can't be described as a gradient of a potential energy, therefore you can't use $m\ddot{r⃗}=−∇⃗ V$.
One elegant way of dealing with these kind of problems is Lagrangian mechanics, a formulation of classical mechanics that focuses more on the energy balance, rather than on the forces. In this way it's usually easier to write down the equations of motion. Sadly, this doesn't imply that these equations can be solved exactly.
